# Issue with harddisk, now showing "Disk Error"

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

My mom's office PC was having some issue recently. That it was not showing any out. When checked, found that the motherboard is defected. Probably because of the frequent power failures or overvoltage which the UPS had failed in protecting.

Now, I have replaced the motherboard with another one. But now it was giving some blue screen error and restarting. So I found that the OS might be corrupted too. Since there is some documents in the Desktop as well as My Doucments, I had to take a backup of it. The best option that I had at that time was to use an Ubuntu CD and Live Boot it. And I did that, and copied the contents to another partition. And then formatted the C drive within the Ubuntu itself.

Then I tried to install Windows XP SP3. It goes through the copying of installation files step and after that, the setup would restart the PC to continue installation. But after that restart, the PC is showing me "Disk Error" in black screen.

When I searched for solutions, I found that it might be issue with Boot Device Priority or it might be because of the issue in Master Boot Record.

The boot device is set to default one by choosing the settings in BIOS to be default. And also, I tried to run the `FIXBOOT` command from the recovery console after inserting the Windows CD. When I tried to do the `FIXMRB` command, it was showing that the Boot Record is invalid or something and was warning that if I continue the other partition would be lost or something.

So shall I continue that? Will it cause loss of data from the other partitions? Because the other partitions contains important datas which at the moment, I can't take backup as of non-availability of a TB sized backup drive!

Answer (score 0):

Backups really need to be onto a separate drive for exactly this reason.

You can use `gparted` with Ubuntu to take a look at the drive and check the partitions for errors.

You can also try installing XP again (although you should really use something else, because XP is no longer supported.)